# How to turn off [Bitlocker Drive Encryption] dialog box?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

Windows 7 always asks when I logged, "Enter password to unlock the drive". I do not want to unlock the drive yet and it's annoying. I'll unlock manually when I need these encrypted data.

How can I turn that feature off? (I'm not asking for disabling Bitlocker.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable automatic unlocking of Bitlocker via the command line tool `manage-bde`?

```
manage-bde -autounlock -disable E:
```

This command should disable autounlock of drive E:

See also [MS Technet documentation of Manage-bde: autounlock](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't use autounlock feature.  also tried the command and got the error: "Already disabled". Truecrypt never beggin me "Can I unlock that drive, please?" Windows asks, asks, and asks continuously.